# Wordpress, ACF relationship array & Post Expirator plugin weird behavior - items in array get lost somehow

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

Ok, I'll try my best to explain this. We (my team) built a custom functionality for our client that combines Advanced Custom Fields and Post Expirator in a way that if posts are scheduled to either publish or expire, they get added / removed from a relationship array created with ACF. The process of publishing posts is as follows:

Client creates a post and schedules the time he wants to publish and expire it. This works without flaws as it's default functionality of Wordpress and Post Expirator plugin. Next, there's a checkbox in the post editor that when checked 'true' hooks into a function that adds and removes that post from a relationship array (it's used for populating a homepage carousel with posts). When we test this locally it works great, however client keeps having problems with posts disappearing from the relationship array randomly, before the post's expiration time.

We do not see this happening on our local testing installation, but we are not managing any data and are not updating the content in any way, so that is the biggest difference between our and client's installations.

We tried all sorts of troubleshooting and tweaking, tried braking our local builds intentionally but could not reproduce the bug. So now I'm reaching out for some fresh ideas as to why those post might be disappearing at random.

Thanks!

Here's the php that handles the ACF relationship array:

```
//Add post to homepage carousel on post update if posts ACF is checked true
function add_post_to_homepage_carousel() {
  $homepage_id      = get_option('page_on_front');
  $post_to_add      = get_post();
  $post_checked     = get_field('add_to_homepage_carousel', $post_to_add->ID);
  $carray           = get_field('carousel_post_selection', $homepage_id);

  if ( !is_array($carray)) {
    $carray = array();
  }

  if ($post_checked === 'true' && !in_array($post_to_add, $carray, true)) {
    array_unshift($carray, $post_to_add);
    update_field('carousel_post_selection', $carray, $homepage_id);
  }
}
add_action('save_post', 'add_post_to_homepage_carousel', 10, 2);
add_action('publish_future_post', 'add_post_to_homepage_carousel', 10, 2);

//clean carousel array if post expired or unset from wp editor
function clear_carousel_array() {
  $homepage_id      = get_option('page_on_front');
  $carray           = get_field('carousel_post_selection', $homepage_id);
  $post_to_remove   = get_post();
  $post_checked     = get_field('add_to_homepage_carousel', $post_to_remove->ID);

  if ( !is_array($carray)) {
    $carray = array();
  }

  if ($post_checked === 'false') {
    if (($key = array_search($post_to_remove, $carray, true)) !== NULL) {
      unset($carray[$key]);
    }
    update_field('carousel_post_selection', $carray, $homepage_id);
  }
}
add_action('save_post', 'clear_carousel_array');
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time messing around with the code, this one got solved, finally, so here's a short write up on fixing the issue.

First thing first, the bug was reproduced some time after writing the OP, and the problem was as follows: post would get added to relationship array fine, the function for removing them also worked, but if you then tried adding the same post again, it would overwrite the first post in the array.

There were problems with both the comparison function `in_array` and the action hook I was using. The hook that did the job eventually turned out to be `acf/save_post` that handled execution of setting and getting the ACF value of `$post_checked` bit better than the default `save_post`.

As array comparison goes, `in_array` was problematic, becuase even if set to strict, it would return `true` when comparing entire post objects. A simple for loop did the trick, comparison was done on post IDs instead of complete post objects.

Here's the revised code. Some things are a bit redundant and the function can be made more elegant still, but it does the job well:

```
function add_remove_carousel($post_ID) {
  $current_post     = get_post();
  $homepage_id      = get_option('page_on_front');
  $carray           = get_field('carousel_post_selection', $homepage_id);
  $post_checked     = get_field('add_to_homepage_carousel', $post_ID);

  if($post_checked) {
    if ($post_checked === 'Yes') {
      $post_in_array = false;
      foreach ($carray as $key => $post_obj) {
        if($post_obj->ID == $post_ID) {
          $post_in_array = true;
          break;
        }    
      }
      if(!$post_in_array) {
        $carray_n = array_merge(array($current_post), $carray);
        $carray_n = array_values($carray_n);
        update_field('carousel_post_selection', $carray_n, $homepage_id);
      }
    }
    elseif ($post_checked === 'No') {
      $post_in_array = false;
      $post_key;
      foreach ($carray as $key => $post_obj) {
        if($post_obj->ID == $post_ID) {
          $post_in_array = true;
          $post_key = $key;
          break;
        }    
      }
      if($post_in_array) {
        $carray_n = array_diff_key($carray, array($post_key));
        $carray_n = array_values($carray_n);
        update_field('carousel_post_selection', $carray_n, $homepage_id);
      }
    }
  }
}

add_action('acf/save_post', 'add_remove_carousel', 11, 1);
```